# PreparedStatement throws syntax error

Tags: java, mysql, jdbc, prepared-statement

Im preparing a query using PreparedStatements and it runs fine when i hardcode te query with the condition parameter.

but throws error , if the parameter is passed from setString() method.

```
com.mysql.jdbc.JDBC4PreparedStatement@2cf63e26: select * from linkedin_page_mess ages where company_id = '2414183' com.mysql.jdbc.exceptions.jdbc4.MySQLSyntaxErrorException: You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MySQL server version for the right syntax to use near '?' at line 1
```

In the error log, above my query looks fine.

```
public JSONObject getLinkedInMessages(String compId)
    {
            linlogger.log(Level.INFO, "Called getLinkedInMessages method");
        Connection conn = null;
        Statement stmt = null;
        ResultSet rs = null;

        JSONObject resObj = new JSONObject();
        JSONArray tempArray = new JSONArray();
        try
        {
            conn = InitOrGetConnection();
            String query = "select * from linkedin_page_messages where company_id = ?";
            PreparedStatement pst=conn.prepareStatement(query);
            pst.setString(1, compId);
            System.out.println("\n\n"+pst.toString());
            rs= pst.executeQuery(query);


             // process resultset logics
        }
       catch(Exception e)
        {   
            System.out.println(e);
            linlogger.log(Level.INFO, "Exception occured "+e.toString());
        }
    }
```

Is there anything wrong with the PreparedStatements?

Comment: Looking at the error message, there seems to have a space in `linkedin_page_mess ages`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

remove the parameter in this line:

```
rs= pst.executeQuery(query);
```

It must be

```
rs= pst.executeQuery();
```

Because the statement is prepared at `PreparedStatement pst=conn.prepareStatement(query);`

`execute(String sql)` is inherited from [Statement](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/sql/Statement.html#execute(java.lang.String)) and will execute the satement (sql) without prepared it.

Comment: On a `PreparedStatement`, `execute(String)` **must** throw an exception (see the javadoc), however it does so on MySQL only by accident.

Answer (score 2):

Remove the parameter from

```
rs= pst.executeQuery(query);
```

change to

```
rs= pst.executeQuery();
```

If you pass query in `pst.executeQuery(query);` as parameter then this passed `query` string take priority over the `query` string you passed in `conn.prepareStatement(query);` and since in `query`(`select * from linkedin_page_messages where company_id = ?`) you dint pass parameter you get the error.